# Getting 401 unauthorzed error while creating order with Shipstation REST API and PHP

Tags: php, api

I am trying to connect Shipstation with my website using REST API and creating order which can be added to manual store inside Shipstation by default. However, I am getting error 401 unauthorised continuously, even I copied API key and API secret from Shipstation account and passed its base64 form to Authorization header.

Here is my Simple Post Request :

```
$api_key = 'SS_KEY';
$api_secret = 'SS_SECRET';
$token = base64_encode($api_key.':'.$api_secret);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/createorder/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
  "orderNumber": "TEST-ORDER-API-DOCS",
  "orderStatus": "awaiting_shipment",
  "customerUsername": "abc",
  "customerEmail": "headhoncho@whitehouse.gov",
  "billTo": {
    "name": "Inam Ali",
    "company": "abc",
    "street1": "1",
    "street2": null,
    "street3": null,
    "city": "Pesh",
    "state": "KPK",
    "postalCode": 25000,
    "country": "Pakistan",
    "phone": "0315333333",
    "residential": true
  },
  "shipTo": {
    "name": "Inam Ali",
    "company": "US Govt",
    "street1": "1600 Pennsylvania Ave",
    "street2": "Oval Office",
    "street3": null,
    "city": "Washington",
    "state": "DC",
    "postalCode": "20500",
    "country": "US",
    "phone": "555-555-5555",
    "residential": true
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "lineItemKey": "vd08-MSLbtx",
      "name": "Test item #1",
      "imageUrl": null,
      "quantity": 2,
      "unitPrice": 99.99,
      "taxAmount": 2.5,
     
      
      
    }
  ],
  "amountPaid": 218.73,
  "taxAmount": 5,
  "tagIds": [
    53974
  ]
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'host: ssapi.shipstation.com',
    'Authorization: Basic '.$token
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Please show us the output from `echo $response;`

Comment: the output is simple, 401 unauthoized

Comment: @Inam getting the same, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes, in my case, the client had unsubscribed from the shipstation due to which the token was not validating, when he subscribed back, then it worked fine. 
You can also ask from the support team about the problem, they will help you instantly.